# HTTP GET url with Json parameters in Android

Tags: android, json, http

I am having the following API call:

`http://rollout.gr/api/?query={%22search%22:%22places%22,%22page%22:1}`

This API call is executed correctly in my browser. But when I use a `DefaultHttpClient` to execute this url in my Android application, I get a null response.

I suppose the problem is the JSON data in the HTTP url. Thus, I would like to ask which is the proper way to handle such url in an Android application?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Could you show us your HTTP code? Specifically, are setting JSON in your accept header? Your browser probably sends \*/\* (check this using proxy software like Fiddler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accolades aren't valid URL characters. The browser is userfriendly enough to automatically URL-encode them, but DefaultHttpClient isn't. The correct line to use from code is:

```
http://rollout.gr/api/?query=http://rollout.gr/api/?query=%7b%22search%22:%22places%22,%22page%22:1%7d
```

Note the encoding for the accolades (`%7b`, `%7d`).

Comment: Thanks mate! It finally worked! I had encoded the url before too, but I had no result. Thanks in any case!

Comment: No problem, you answered your own question really. Glad things worked out!

Comment: I have the same problem. i keep getting nul value (unauthorized 401!) any idea?

Comment: @Snake That doesn't sound like the same problem at all, you are dealing with a service that requires authentication. By all means start a new question providing the details.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be the strictmode here.
I recommend to do http request in threads or asynctasks. strictmode doesnt let app do http reauest in uithread. maybe your console shows a warning and you get null from http response because of this.

This project may solve your problem:

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: Hey! I execute the DefaultHttpClient inside an Async Task, so this not the problem. I also tried with any other url and it works fine, that's why I ended up that the problem might be the json parameter in the GET request.

Comment: I verified the jason. there is no problem in json syntax.
I may speak more acurate if you show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your particular HTTP initialization code, I'm going to assume you didn't provide an explicit JSON accept header. A lot of REST endpoints require this.

```
httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

Comment: No this is not the problem.. If for example I call this: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23example I get the result correct. I also tried to use other libraries like loopj and I got an error for invalid character in the url for character "{". Thus the problem lies in the JSON data in the url.

Comment: You could very well be correct. However, do note that the fact that the twitter API works doesn't invalidate my suggestion. Some endpoints require specific JSON accept headers (for example, those build with a framework that provides both JSON and XML responses), others don't.

Comment: I checked, and you are correct about the invalid characters. This answer does not solve your problem, added another one.